# PatchDiff2 Outputting results to a Text File

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, patch-reversing, tool-bindiff

I have attempted working with BinDiff to compare files and save the output, but unfortunately I am unable to save it to anything other than a .BinDiff or .BinExport file type. To try and counter this problem I attempted using another IDA plug-in, PatchDiff2. I am running into the same problem with this software. I can get the comparison and it is exactly what I want but I have no means of sending it to a text,pdf,or html file (which  I need it to be). I am running IDA 6.5 PatchDiff 2.0.10b and BinDiff 4.0.

EDIT: I understand that this is open source, however I am wondering if there is a built in plug-in to simply save the results as a text file, pdf, html etc.

Answer (score 2):

PatchDiff2 is [open-source](http://patchdiff2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), so you can edit it yourself to write the output to a file.

Comment: What file would I edit exactly? patchdiff2.plx? I am running linux ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It's open-source. See the link I posted above.

Comment: I understand that, I am still quite new to this field and I was wondering if you have any recommendations on how to go about doing this. Would it require IDAPython? How would I compile the various components to recreate the plug-in?

Comment: Please ask software development questions at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @JasonGeffner I think questions about tools are on-topic.

Comment: @heinrich5991, "How would I compile the various components" is a software development question.